# What is the time complexity of this piece of code?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

```
sum=0;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  for(j=0;j<i*i;j++)
    for(k=0;k<j;k++)
      sum++;
```

What is the time complexity of the above program? I think it should be O(n^4). Can someone please derive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple when you put the different elements you have in the right places. For instance, you may use Sigma notation:

[image]

Here, if you display the final value of ***sum***, you'll realize it's equal to ***T(n)***'s closed form. Just give it a try (you could also do simplications).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the input n

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) is O(n)

for(j=0;j<i*i;j++) is O(n^2 /2) since depends on i whose value goes from 1 to n (average of 1..2 is n/2).

for(k=0;k<j;k++) is O((n^2 /2) / 2) since depends j goes from 0 to i*i
```

Then since they are nested, the complexity is the product of the loops complexity  O(n * (n^2 /2) * ((n^2 /2) / 2)) = O(n^5 / 8)

Which is in the order n^5 or O(n^5)

Comment: I didn't get how did you write in third loop the complexity as O((n^2/2)/2). Can you please explain